# Using purrr to iteratively replace strings in a dataframe column

Tags: r, gsub, purrr

I would like to use `purrr` to iteratively run several string replacements on a dataframe column with the `gsub()` function.

This is the example dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(Year = "2019",
                 Text = c(rep("a aa", 5), 
                          rep("a bb", 3), 
                          rep("a cc", 2)))

> df
   Year Text
1  2019 a aa
2  2019 a aa
3  2019 a aa
4  2019 a aa
5  2019 a aa
6  2019 a bb
7  2019 a bb
8  2019 a bb
9  2019 a cc
10 2019 a cc
```

This is how I would normally run the string replacement, and the desired result.

```
df$Text <- gsub("aa", "One", df$Text, fixed = T)
df$Text <- gsub("bb", "Two", df$Text, fixed = T)
df$Text <- gsub("cc", "Three", df$Text, fixed = T)

> df
   Year    Text
1  2019   a One
2  2019   a One
3  2019   a One
4  2019   a One
5  2019   a One
6  2019   a Two
7  2019   a Two
8  2019   a Two
9  2019 a Three
10 2019 a Three
```

However this is unrealistic to use as the list of string replacements grows, so I tried to use `purrr` to iterate such changes using a list of `patterns` and `replacements` but I've only managed to produce error messages. I expect the code to iterate through `text_pattern` and `text_replacement` and run `gsub` on `df$Text` for each pair of pattern/replacement. The example is below along with the error messages.

```
text_pattern <- c("aa", "bb", "cc")
text_replacement <- c("One", "Two", "Three")

walk2(text_pattern, text_replacement, function(...){
  gsub(text_pattern, text_replacement, df$Text, fixed = F)
  }
)

Warning messages:
1: In gsub(text_former, text_replace, df$Text, fixed = F) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In gsub(text_former, text_replace, df$Text, fixed = F) :
  argument 'replacement' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In gsub(text_former, text_replace, df$Text, fixed = F) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
4: In gsub(text_former, text_replace, df$Text, fixed = F) :
  argument 'replacement' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
5: In gsub(text_former, text_replace, df$Text, fixed = F) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
6: In gsub(text_former, text_replace, df$Text, fixed = F) :
  argument 'replacement' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Is it possible to accomplish this using functions from `purrr`? Or alternatively am I trying to use the wrong tool and is there a different function I should be using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `reduce2`

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
df$Text <- reduce2(text_pattern, text_replacement, ~ str_replace(..1, ..2, ..3), 
           .init = df$Text)
df$Text
#[1] "a One"   "a One"   "a One"   "a One"   "a One"   "a Two"   "a Two"   "a Two"   "a Three" "a Three"
```

---

Or without using anonymous function call

```
reduce2(text_pattern, text_replacement, .init = df$Text, str_replace)
```

Answer (score 4):

@akrun's answer is great, however there are a few intermediate points you may also find useful in understanding `purrr` better.

1. `walk2` won't return output,  it just returns the first input vector.

   From the [docs](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html):

   > walk() calls .f for its side-effect and returns the input .x.

   The closest analog for what you're doing is `map2`, but see below for why that's also not quite what you need.
2. Arguments inside `purrr` functions like `map` and `walk` refer to generic representations of the vectors being iterated over.

   You have a couple of options for how to refer to input vectors.  One is to name the arguments in `function(...)`.  For example, with `function(x, y)` then this will produce error-free output:

   ```
   map2(text_pattern, text_replacement, function(x, y){
     gsub(x, y, df$Text, fixed = F)
   }
   )  # switching to map2() because walk2 gives silent output
   ```

   You can also use `~` syntax and then refer to the input iterables as `.x` and `.y`:

   ```
   map2(text_pattern, text_replacement, ~gsub(.x, .y, df$Text, fixed = F))
   ```
3. The output isn't what you are expecting.

   `purrr` methods like `map` and `walk` loop over the entire vector for each pattern.  The output for both of the code snippets in 2. is the following:

   ```
   [[1]]
    [1] "a One" "a One" "a One" "a One" "a One" "a bb"  "a bb"  "a bb"  "a cc"  "a cc" 

   [[2]]
    [1] "a aa"  "a aa"  "a aa"  "a aa"  "a aa"  "a Two" "a Two" "a Two" "a cc"  "a cc" 

   [[3]]
    [1] "a aa"    "a aa"    "a aa"    "a aa"    "a aa"    "a bb"    "a bb"    "a bb"   
    [9] "a Three" "a Three"
   ```

   So even fixing the syntax, you're still getting a three-element list, the contents of each element being the results of the replacement operation for each pair of `text_pattern`-`text_replacement`.  There's still a smush operation that needs to happen to bring them all together with just the replaced elements.   That's what @akrun's shift to `reduce2` accomplishes.

   One additional note on `reduce` syntax - the arguments `..1`, `..2`, `..3` refer to the inputs on each iteration, and the use of `.init` makes the first argument (`..1`) equal to `df$Text`.  `..2` and `..3` are what, in the earlier examples of `map2`, were `.x` and `.y`, respectively (ie pattern and replacement values).  See the [`reduce` docs](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/reduce.html) for more.

Comment: Thanks for the great in-depth explanation. I assumed the side-effect of my `walk` call would be the string replacement in the global dataframe but it looks like that is not the case. Looks like I've got a lot more learning to do!