# Use purrr::map to rewrite a vector as in for loop

Tags: r, purrr

How can I use `purrr::map()` to return the result of the for loop of the example:

```
vct_string <- c("old ccar","new carr", "house", "oold house")

df_correction <- data.frame(
  pattern  = c("ccar", "carr", "oold"),
  replacement = c("car", "car", "old"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

for(i in 1:nrow(df_correction)){
  vct_string <- pmap(df_correction, gsub, x = vct_string)[[i]]
}

> vct_string
[1] "old car"   "new car"   "house"     "old house"
```

Comment: It looks like this existing question has an answer that applies to your question as well:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60046482/using-purrr-to-iteratively-replace-strings-in-a-dataframe-column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to recursively modify your vector so in my opinion this is classic case of usage of reduce family function here.  So do this, where you will have to pass your vector to `.init` argument of `purrr::reduce` to get the desired output

```r
purrr::reduce(seq(nrow(df_correction)), .init = vct_string, ~ gsub(df_correction$pattern[.y], df_correction$replacement[.y], .x))

#> [1] "old car"   "new car"   "house"     "old house"
```

This will even do multiple replacements in elements of given vector.  see this

```
#modified example
vct_string <- c("old ccar","new carr", "house", "oold carr")

purrr::reduce(seq(nrow(df_correction)), .init = vct_string, ~ gsub(df_correction$pattern[.y], df_correction$replacement[.y], .x))
[1] "old car" "new car" "house"   "old car"
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you do not need any of the `ReduceMap` functions. Just use `str_replace_all` its vectorized

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(vct_string, set_names(df_correction$replacement, df_correction$pattern))

[1] "old car"   "new car"   "house"     "old house"
```

Comment: Bingo! I was trying to use this function but couldn't thought of using set_names.  +1

Answer (score 1):

First write a function for the replacements

```
word_correct <- function(string) {
  df_correction <- data.frame(
    pattern  = c("old ccar", " new carr", "oold house", "house"), # changed from OP
    replacement = c("car", "car", "old", "house"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
  df_correction[ which(df_correction$pattern == string), "replacement"]
}

# Testing
word_correct("oold")
word_correct("ccar")
```

Then you can pass that function as an argument in `purrr::map`

```
map_chr(vct_string, word_correct) # using map_chr to return a vector instead of a list which is what map returns
```

Since you are using a mapping table to replace individual words, you can actually use `map` in a second function to get your desired results.

```
vct_string <- c("old ccar","new carr", "house", "oold house")

single_word_correct <- function(string) {
  
  df_correction <- data.frame(
    pattern  = c("ccar", "carr", "oold"),
    replacement = c("car", "car", "old"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
  if(string %in% df_correction$pattern){
    df_correction[ which(df_correction$pattern == string), "replacement"]
  } else {
    string
  }
}
multi_word_correct <- function(string){
  strings <- strsplit(string, " ")[[1]]
  paste(map_chr(strings, single_word_correct), collapse = " ")
}

map_chr(vct_string, multi_word_correct)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you could do it with base::Reduce:

```
Reduce(function(x, y) {
  gsub(df_correction[y, 1], df_correction[y, 2], x)
}, init = vct_string, 1:nrow(df_correction))

[1] "old car"   "new car"   "house"     "old house"
```